# Passing something to main app.js file in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is ther a any way to pass redux state  to  main app.js file in react/redux? I wan't to change classname based on redux state. I tried to combine even with local storage but still can't make a satisfying solution.

This is my main app.js file

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <div style={{display: 'flex'}} >
                        <Navbar/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(MainProfile)} exact path="/profile"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(MyDiet)} exact path="/diet"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(AllDiets)} exact path="/alldiets"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(EditProfile)} exact path="/editprofile"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(WorkoutPlan)} exact path="/workout"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsNotAuthenticated(Login)} exact path="/login"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(EditDiet)} exact path="/edit/:id"/>
                            <Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(EditDiet)} exact path="/edit/:id"/>
                            {/*<Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(UsersDiet)} exact path="/usersdiet"/>*/}
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default (App)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the redux state in the component that is wrapped in your `Provider` then you might consider moving the `Provider` component to where you initially render your React.

**entry.jsx**

```
const store = createStore(...);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
      </Provider>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**app.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`${this.state.someData ? 'someClassA' : 'someClassB'}`} >
                <Navbar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route>'s...  
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    someData: state.foo
  }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
)(App)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already using store using provider in the app. So, you can use:

```
store.getState().redux_state_name
```